# Star and Half Star Rating in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, e-commerce

I want to display average product ratings in star. The values are displaying good but I want to show half star if the value is in float.

My blade view:

```
<div class="rating">
  @for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
    @if($product->ratings->avg('rating') > $i)
      <span class="icon-ratings"><i class="icon-rating icon-rating-x"></i></span>
    @else
      <span class="icon-ratings"><i class="icon-rating icon-rating-o"></i></span>
    @endif
  @endfor
 &nbsp; <div style="float:left">{{$product->ratings->avg('rating')}}</div>
</div>
```

The average value is showing 4.5. But all the 5 stars are filled with golden color. I want to fill half last star as that is a floating number.

Answer (score 0):

use `floor()` function to detect float value like this

```
.................
@for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)

  <?php
    $thisRating = product->ratings->avg('rating')
    if(floor($thisRating) != $thisRating) {
      $hasHalfVal = 1;
    } else {
      $hasHalfVal = 0;
    }
  ?>

   @if($thisRating > $i && $hasHalfVal == 0)
     <span class="icon-ratings"><i class="icon-rating icon-rating-x"></i></span>
   @else if($thisRating > $i && $hasHalfVal == 1) 
     <span class="icon-ratings"><i class="icon-rating icon-rating-half"></i></span>
   @else
     <span class="icon-ratings"><i class="icon-rating icon-rating-o"></i></span>
   @endif

 .................
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as below. For example in below answer I use font-awesome.

```
@for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
    @if($product->ratings->avg('rating') < $i)
        @if (round($product->ratings->avg('rating')) == $i)


            <li class="list-inline-item me-0 small"><i
                    class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-warning"></i></li>
            @continue
        @endif
        <li class="list-inline-item me-0 small"><i
                class="far fa-star text-warning"></i></li>
        @continue
    @endif
    <li class="list-inline-item me-0 small"><i
            class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i></li>
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
    $thisRating = product->ratings->avg('rating')
    if(floor($thisRating) != $thisRating) {
      $hasHalfVal = 1;
    } else {
      $hasHalfVal = 0;
    }
  ?>
 if($hasHalfVal = 1){
@for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
@if ($i<=$thisRating){
<span class="icon-ratings"><i class="icon-rating icon-rating-x"></i></span>
}elseif(($i - $review->rating) = 1){
 <span class="icon-ratings"><i class="icon-rating icon-rating-half"></i></span>
}else {
<span class="icon-ratings"><i class="icon-rating icon-rating-o"></i></span> }}
@endfor
}else{
@for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
@if ($i<=$review->rating){
<span class="icon-ratings"><i class="icon-rating icon-rating-x"></i></span>
}else{
<span class="icon-ratings"><i class="icon-rating icon-rating-o"></i></span> }}
}}}
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
                    $ratingAvg = $review->avg('rating');
                 ?>

            @for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)

                <?php
                          $checkstar =$ratingAvg - $i;                   
                ?>

                      @if($checkstar >= 1 )

                      <small class="fas fa-star"></small>

                      @elseif( $checkstar < 1 && $checkstar > 0)

                           <small class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></small>

                      @else
                            <small class="far fa-star"></small>
                      @endif
               @endfor
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).